# Firebase when is last time onChildAdded is being called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to display a loading spinner. For this I need to know when Firebase is done loading with all the childs. Below function just keeps getting called a random amount of times, and I do not know when it is the last time. A query for the amount of records would also solve this problem.

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

im using this code and it works well.
you should use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` on your `query`.

`noViewTxtView` is a TextView that tells the user there's no posts if there's no childs.
and `loadingLayout` is my custom progressBar.

for more info refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982795/2968988) answer

```
 void setProgressBar() {
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            hasChilderen = dataSnapshot.hasChildren();
            if (!hasChilderen) {
                noViewTxtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            query.removeEventListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```